# Как в NetCoreApp получить путь к программе?

Tags: c#, .net-core

> Ошибка    CS0117  "Assembly" не содержит определение для
>   "GetExecutingAssembly"

```
var AppDirectory = ((new DirectoryInfo(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)).Parent).FullName
```

Использую `NetCoreApp 1.1`. Отсутствует `GetExecutingAssembly`

Но работает нормально при использовании `NetFramework 4.5.2`

Comment: Как насчет `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`?

Comment: @Monk: Там вроде нету доменов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var location = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location;
var directory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(location);
System.Console.WriteLine(directory);
```

Output

```
C:\MyApplication\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.0
```